# Habilitei uma extensão do PHP e aparece um Warning?

Tags: php, oracle11g, warnings

Habilitei a extensão `php_oci8_11g.dll` porém recebo o seguinte alerta.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - %1 nÒo Ú um aplicativo Win32 vßlido.

Já reinstalei o `PHP` várias vezes, mas o erro continua. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Obs: Estou usando `Windows 10` de 64 bits e o meu `PHP` está na versão `5.6.30`.

Comment: O seu PHP é versão?

Comment: Vou colocar na pergunta

Comment: Você está instalando o PHP através de algum pacote (xamp, wamp, etcc) ou de forma nativa? O PHP é x86 ou x64?

Comment: @GabrielHeming nativo e x86

Comment: Se adicionar no google apenas o nome da DLL, encontrará inúmeros resultados para o seu problema. Três links apenas do stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709005/php-oci8-11g-dll-is-not-a-valid-win32-application
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460945/php-oci8-unable-to-load-not-a-valid-win32-application
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825405/php-warning-at-startup-while-trying-to-load-php-oci8-dll
https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_oci8_with_32-bit_php

Comment: @GabrielHeming preciso que seja nessa versão, a segunda resposta não responde a pergunta.

Comment: Todos falam a mesma coisa, procure pela DLL 32 bits compilada no VC11. É provável que esteja utilizando uma em outra

Comment: @GabrielHeming estou usando a de 32 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi, tive que reinstalar o [Oracle Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html), baixei uma versão com `Thread Safe` do `PHP` e a seguinte [DLL](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.12/windows).